# JOOQ: No schemata were loaded?

Tags: java, maven, h2, jooq

I am trying to learn `JOOQ` by using it in my project.

Here is my entity

```
@Entity
public class User {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String userExternalId;
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String email;
    private String clientId;
    private String clientSecret;
    private boolean active;

    public User(@Nonnull final String userExternalId, @Nonnull final String email,
                @Nonnull final String clientId, @Nonnull final String clientSecret) {
        id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        this.userExternalId = userExternalId;
        this.email = email;
        this.clientId = clientId;
        this.clientSecret = clientSecret;
        active = true;
    }

    public User() {
    }

    @Nonnull
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @Nonnull
    public String getUserExternalId() {
        return userExternalId;
    }

    @Nonnull
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    @Nonnull
    public String getClientId() {
        return clientId;
    }

    @Nonnull
    public String getClientSecret() {
        return clientSecret;
    }

    public boolean isActive() {
        return active;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", externalUserId='" + userExternalId + '\'' +
                ", email='" + email + '\'' +
                ", clientId='" + clientId + '\'' +
                ", clientSecret='" + clientSecret + '\'' +
                ", active=" + active +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Here is the `UserService` class

```
public class UserService {
    private final EntityManager entityManager;

    public UserService(@Nonnull final EntityManager entityManager) {
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }

    @Nonnull
    public User createUser(@Nonnull final User user) {
        entityManager.persist(user);
        return user;
    }
}
```

My `persistence/pom.xml` looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <artifactId>oauth</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.self</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>persistence</artifactId>
    <name>OAuth: Persistence</name>

    <properties>
        <hibernate-jpa-2.0-api.version>1.0.1.Final</hibernate-jpa-2.0-api.version>
        <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>
        <hibernate-entitymanager.version>4.3.6.Final</hibernate-entitymanager.version>
        <h2.version>1.4.180</h2.version>
        <querydsl-version>3.4.2</querydsl-version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate-jpa-2.0-api.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
            <artifactId>jooq</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
            <artifactId>jooq-meta</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
            <artifactId>jooq-codegen</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate-entitymanager.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>${h2.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <!-- Specify the maven code generator plugin -->
                <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
                <artifactId>jooq-codegen-maven</artifactId>
                <version>3.4.1</version>

                <!-- The plugin should hook into the generate goal -->
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>

                <!-- Manage the plugin's dependency. In this example, we'll use a H2 database -->
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
                        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
                        <version>${h2.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>

                <!-- Specify the plugin configuration.
                     The configuration format is the same as for the standalone code generator -->
                <configuration>
                    <!-- JDBC connection parameters -->
                    <jdbc>
                        <driver>org.h2.Driver</driver>
                        <url>jdbc:h2:mem:oauth</url>
                        <user>sa</user>
                        <password></password>
                    </jdbc>

                    <!-- Generator parameters -->
                    <generator>
                        <name>org.jooq.util.DefaultGenerator</name>
                        <database>
                            <name>org.jooq.util.h2.H2Database</name>
                            <includes>.*</includes>
                            <excludes></excludes>
                            <inputSchema>public</inputSchema>
                        </database>
                        <target>
                            <packageName>com.self.oauth.persistence.entities</packageName>
                            <directory>target/generated-sources/jooq</directory>
                        </target>
                    </generator>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

When I run `mvn -pl persistence`, the logs look like

```
➜  oauth git:(master) ✗ mvn -pl persistence
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective settings
[WARNING] 'usePluginRegistry' is deprecated and has no effect. @ /Users/harith/.m2/settings.xml
[WARNING] 
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] Using the builder org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder with a thread count of 1
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building OAuth: Persistence 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ persistence ---
[INFO] Deleting /Users/harith/code/IdeaProjects/others/oauth/persistence/target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- jooq-codegen-maven:3.4.1:generate (default) @ persistence ---
[INFO] Using this configuration:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<configuration xmlns="http://www.jooq.org/xsd/jooq-codegen-3.4.0.xsd">
    <jdbc>
        <driver>org.h2.Driver</driver>
        <url>jdbc:h2:mem:oauth</url>
        <user>sa</user>
    </jdbc>
    <generator>
        <name>org.jooq.util.DefaultGenerator</name>
        <database>
            <name>org.jooq.util.h2.H2Database</name>
            <includes>.*</includes>
            <excludes></excludes>
            <includeExcludeColumns>false</includeExcludeColumns>
            <recordVersionFields></recordVersionFields>
            <recordTimestampFields></recordTimestampFields>
            <syntheticPrimaryKeys></syntheticPrimaryKeys>
            <overridePrimaryKeys></overridePrimaryKeys>
            <dateAsTimestamp>false</dateAsTimestamp>
            <unsignedTypes>true</unsignedTypes>
            <inputSchema>public</inputSchema>
            <outputSchemaToDefault>false</outputSchemaToDefault>
        </database>
        <target>
            <packageName>com.self.oauth.persistence.entities</packageName>
            <directory>/Users/harith/code/IdeaProjects/others/oauth/persistence/target/generated-sources/jooq</directory>
        </target>
    </generator>
</configuration>

[INFO] License parameters       
[INFO] ----------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]   Thank you for using jOOQ and jOOQ's code generator
[INFO]                          
[INFO] Database parameters      
[INFO] ----------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]   dialect                : H2
[INFO]   URL                    : jdbc:h2:mem:oauth
[INFO]   target dir             : /Users/harith/code/IdeaProjects/others/oauth/persistence/target/generated-sources/jooq
[INFO]   target package         : com.self.oauth.persistence.entities
[INFO]   includes               : [.*]
[INFO]   excludes               : []
[INFO]   includeExcludeColumns  : false
[INFO] ----------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]                          
[INFO] DefaultGenerator parameters
[INFO] ----------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]   strategy               : class org.jooq.util.DefaultGeneratorStrategy
[INFO]   deprecated             : true
[INFO]   generated annotation   : true
[INFO]   JPA annotations        : false
[INFO]   validation annotations : false
[INFO]   instance fields        : true
[INFO]   records                : true
[INFO]   pojos                  : false
[INFO]   immutable pojos        : false
[INFO]   interfaces             : false
[INFO]   daos                   : false
[INFO]   relations              : true
[INFO]   global references      : true
[INFO] ----------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]                          
[INFO] Generation remarks       
[INFO] ----------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]   none                   
[INFO]                          
[INFO] ----------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Emptying                 : /Users/harith/code/IdeaProjects/others/oauth/persistence/target/generated-sources/jooq/com/self/oauth/persistence/entities
[WARNING] No schemata were loaded  : Please check your connection settings, and whether your database (and your database version!) is really supported by jOOQ. Also, check the case-sensitivity in your configured <inputSchema/> elements : [public]
[INFO] Generating schemata      : Total: 0
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ persistence ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ persistence ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 2 source files to /Users/harith/code/IdeaProjects/others/oauth/persistence/target/classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ persistence ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ persistence ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to /Users/harith/code/IdeaProjects/others/oauth/persistence/target/test-classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ persistence ---
[INFO] Surefire report directory: /Users/harith/code/IdeaProjects/others/oauth/persistence/target/surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running com.self.oauth.persistence.entities.UserServiceTest
Aug 09, 2014 9:28:15 AM org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence logDeprecation
WARN: HHH015016: Encountered a deprecated javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider [org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence]; use [org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider] instead.
Aug 09, 2014 9:28:15 AM org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence logDeprecation
WARN: HHH015016: Encountered a deprecated javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider [org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence]; use [org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider] instead.
Aug 09, 2014 9:28:15 AM org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence logDeprecation
WARN: HHH015016: Encountered a deprecated javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider [org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence]; use [org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider] instead.
Aug 09, 2014 9:28:15 AM org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper logPersistenceUnitInformation
INFO: HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: oauthTest
    ...]
Aug 09, 2014 9:28:15 AM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.6.Final}
Aug 09, 2014 9:28:15 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
Aug 09, 2014 9:28:15 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
Aug 09, 2014 9:28:15 AM org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl processProperties
WARN: HHH000059: Defining hibernate.transaction.flush_before_completion=true ignored in HEM
Aug 09, 2014 9:28:15 AM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.5.Final}
Aug 09, 2014 9:28:15 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH000402: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
Aug 09, 2014 9:28:15 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH000401: using driver [org.h2.Driver] at URL [jdbc:h2:mem:oauth]
Aug 09, 2014 9:28:15 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH000046: Connection properties: {user=sa, password=****}
Aug 09, 2014 9:28:15 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH000006: Autocommit mode: false
Aug 09, 2014 9:28:15 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
Aug 09, 2014 9:28:15 AM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
Aug 09, 2014 9:28:15 AM org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory <init>
INFO: HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
Aug 09, 2014 9:28:15 AM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
INFO: HHH000228: Running hbm2ddl schema update
Aug 09, 2014 9:28:15 AM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
INFO: HHH000102: Fetching database metadata
Aug 09, 2014 9:28:15 AM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
INFO: HHH000396: Updating schema
Aug 09, 2014 9:28:15 AM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.DatabaseMetadata getTableMetadata
INFO: HHH000262: Table not found: User
Aug 09, 2014 9:28:15 AM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.DatabaseMetadata getTableMetadata
INFO: HHH000262: Table not found: User
Aug 09, 2014 9:28:15 AM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.DatabaseMetadata getTableMetadata
INFO: HHH000262: Table not found: User
Aug 09, 2014 9:28:15 AM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
INFO: HHH000232: Schema update complete
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        User
        (active, clientId, clientSecret, email, userExternalId, id) 
    values
        (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Aug 09, 2014 9:28:16 AM org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence logDeprecation
WARN: HHH015016: Encountered a deprecated javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider [org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence]; use [org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider] instead.
Aug 09, 2014 9:28:16 AM org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence logDeprecation
WARN: HHH015016: Encountered a deprecated javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider [org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence]; use [org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider] instead.
Aug 09, 2014 9:28:16 AM org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence logDeprecation
WARN: HHH015016: Encountered a deprecated javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider [org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence]; use [org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider] instead.
Aug 09, 2014 9:28:16 AM org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper logPersistenceUnitInformation
INFO: HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: oauthTest
    ...]
Aug 09, 2014 9:28:16 AM org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl processProperties
WARN: HHH000059: Defining hibernate.transaction.flush_before_completion=true ignored in HEM
Aug 09, 2014 9:28:16 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH000402: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
Aug 09, 2014 9:28:16 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH000401: using driver [org.h2.Driver] at URL [jdbc:h2:mem:oauth]
Aug 09, 2014 9:28:16 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH000046: Connection properties: {user=sa, password=****}
Aug 09, 2014 9:28:16 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH000006: Autocommit mode: false
Aug 09, 2014 9:28:16 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
Aug 09, 2014 9:28:16 AM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
Aug 09, 2014 9:28:16 AM org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory <init>
INFO: HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
Aug 09, 2014 9:28:16 AM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
INFO: HHH000228: Running hbm2ddl schema update
Aug 09, 2014 9:28:16 AM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
INFO: HHH000102: Fetching database metadata
Aug 09, 2014 9:28:16 AM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
INFO: HHH000396: Updating schema
Aug 09, 2014 9:28:16 AM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000261: Table found: OAUTH.PUBLIC.USER
Aug 09, 2014 9:28:16 AM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000037: Columns: [clientid, clientsecret, userexternalid, active, id, email]
Aug 09, 2014 9:28:16 AM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000108: Foreign keys: []
Aug 09, 2014 9:28:16 AM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000126: Indexes: [primary_key_2, uk_e6gkqunxajvyxl5uctpl2vl2p_index_2]
Aug 09, 2014 9:28:16 AM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
INFO: HHH000232: Schema update complete
Aug 09, 2014 9:28:16 AM org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerFactoryRegistry addEntityManagerFactory
WARN: HHH000436: Entity manager factory name (oauthTest) is already registered.  If entity manager will be clustered or passivated, specify a unique value for property 'hibernate.ejb.entitymanager_factory_name'
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        User
        (active, clientId, clientSecret, email, userExternalId, id) 
    values
        (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 1.112 sec

Results :

Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) @ persistence ---
[INFO] Building jar: /Users/harith/code/IdeaProjects/others/oauth/persistence/target/persistence-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-sortpom-plugin:2.3.0:sort (default) @ persistence ---
[INFO] Sorting file /Users/harith/code/IdeaProjects/others/oauth/persistence/pom.xml
[INFO] Pom file is already sorted, exiting
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @ persistence ---
[INFO] Installing /Users/harith/code/IdeaProjects/others/oauth/persistence/target/persistence-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar to /Users/harith/.m2/repository/com/self/persistence/1.0-SNAPSHOT/persistence-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] Installing /Users/harith/code/IdeaProjects/others/oauth/persistence/pom.xml to /Users/harith/.m2/repository/com/self/persistence/1.0-SNAPSHOT/persistence-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.892 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2014-08-09T09:28:16-08:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 19M/84M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Question**

Why the sources not generated by `JOOQ`? What am I missing?

P.S. I am using `Java 1.8`

Comment: what is pl persistence for?

Answer (score 1):

You're using the following H2 JDBC URL:

```
jdbc:h2:mem:oauth
```

According to the [H2 database docs](http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#in_memory_databases), this means that no data is persisted:

> For certain use cases (for example: rapid prototyping, testing, high performance operations, read-only databases), it may not be required to persist data, or persist changes to the data. This database supports the in-memory mode, where the data is not persisted.

It is quite possible that the database is not persisted between consecutive runs of your Maven plugins.

In addition to this, from the Maven log output, it looks as though the jOOQ code generator is run *before* Hibernate's hbm2dll tool.

A workaround (yet maybe not a sound solution) would be to use H2's file-based ["embedded connection"](http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#embedded_databases):

```
jdbc:h2:~/test
```